# routing is not working in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am using routing in angular.js
my code is :

```
   //controllers.js

 var ar= angular.module('ar', []);

ar.controller('lc', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('login.json').success(function(data){
        $scope.art=data;
    })
}])

ar.controller("search", function(){
    this.search='a';

    this.getdata=  function  (searchquery) {
        console.log(searchquery);
    }
});



//main.js (app.js)

var myApp= angular.module('myApp',[
  'ngRoute',
  'ar'
  ]);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
 $routeProvider.
 when('/login', {
  templateUrl: 'inc/login.html',
  controller: 'lc'
 }).
 otherwise({
  redirectTo: '/login'
 });
}]);
```

when i goto the Homepage its not redirect to the Login page and when i click on the login button its not working either.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>

    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>

</head>
<body>



<ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="#/login">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
```

in bottom:
i have include jquery and bootstrap's file.
this is a bootstrap application.
this is live example :
[Live example](http://codebag.org/stackoverflow/)

Comment: can you share html as well...

Comment: let me upload it to the server.

Comment: i have include the live example to the question

Comment: Routes are changing fine. You have not added place to include the template for login

Comment: templateUrl: 'inc/login.html', is this is correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct,but where will this be included in ur html part?

Comment: you mean that i have to place the ng-view in the div where i want to place the login form html right?

Comment: @user3636439 : Yes something like that. Please see my anwser and let me know whether it worked for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routes are specified correctly. What you need is to define the ng-view in your template so that the templates mentioned in specific routes are loaded into the main template

Something like :

```
<div class="page-container">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

`ng-view` will be the place where every template mentioned in the router will be loaded.

Comment: when i add this its give me this error: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $templateRequestProvider <- $templateRequest <- $route <- ngViewDirective

Comment: You should be adding this in main index.html file where you have defined `ng-app="myApp"`. What error did you get?

Comment: yes i have added it into the main index file see the live example i have update the code: http://codebag.org/stackoverflow/#/login

Comment: its working know i have change the files of angular.js

Comment: @user3636439 : I highly recommend that you use ui-router instead of ng-router as its no longer a part of Angular core. Glad the solution worked. cheers.

Comment: but i have got a console error Unexpected token n       see it here http://codebag.org/stackoverflow/#/login

Comment: @user3636439 : possibly related to  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18071379/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-n-in-chrome-console-from-angularjs

Answer (score -1):

i think there might be issue with your path .. its mvc base and routes define your path :)

Comment: the paths are correct .if the paths are incorrect the console have the errors